# JPA validation API

Tags: validation, jpa

Does JPA contains any validation API?

E.g. email property validation like this in hibernate validation:

```
@Email
public String getUserEmail() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bean Validation (JSR303) can be used nicely alongside JPA, but is a separate API. [This](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/03/javaee6-validation) is a very brief introduction to Bean Validation itself, and [see this](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/) for how an introduction of how it can be used with JPA.

Note: Similar to JPA, you will have to pick an implementation, of which there are many. [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) is the reference implementation.

Comment: The site you mentioned (http://antoniogoncalves.org/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/) helped the most immediately and quickly.  thanks